# Flutter - Reading HTTP response where the response body as JSON file and it is received chunks by chunks through Stream method

Tags: android, json, flutter, dart, http

I going to read on a large JSON file through a HTTP response, which may take time some to done it and map to the object class

Is there any method on flutter that able to stream the HTTP response, which I able to put the data into my object class while I stream on the response. The response body will be receiving chunks by chunks by this

Comment: Is it one big object or is it a large array of objects?

Answer (score 0):

There is a asStream Methode in the http package.
your code could look like this:

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class MyObject {
  // Define your object class here
}

Future<void> fetchData() async {
final url = 'your_api_endpoint_here';

final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));

if (response.statusCode == 200) {
final stream = response.bodyBytes.asStream();

final jsonStream = stream
    .transform(Utf8Decoder()) // Decode the bytes to UTF-8 String
    .transform(json.decoder); // Parse the JSON

await for (var jsonObject in jsonStream) {
final myObject = MyObject.fromJson(jsonObject); // Create your   object from JSON
    // Do something with myObject, e.g., add it to a list
   }
 } else {
   throw Exception('Failed to load data');
 }
}
```

Comment: The method 'asStream' isn't defined for the type 'Uint8List'. (Documentation)  Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'asStream'.

I have imported the http but I will get this error.

Comment: you cannot use `bodyBytes`as it requires the whole body to be read, OP wants to read the response in small chunks